# What if a fielder stand on 30 yard circle?

Tags: cricket

What if a fielder stand on 30 yard circle? Is he called an infielder or outfielder. I have also seen that some player also stand some steps outside of 30 yard circle.
So if do not walks inside thd circle while the bowler delivers the bowl, is he counted as a fielder outside the circle?

Comment: Which competition(s) are you referring to? As you're hopefully aware, the general laws of cricket have no 30 yard restrictions.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Specific competition regulations cover this, as it's not covered in the Laws of the game. These regulations usually say that the fielder must be inside the circle at the instant of delivery, so if he's not there he's outside and subject to the relevant penalty.

Comment: Which competition are you referring to? As noted in my answer, the restriction in one-day internationals is on the number of fielders *outside* the 30 yard markers, so a fielder on the markers is an infielder.

Answer (score 2):

For one-day internationals, being *on* the 30 yard markers makes the fielder an infielder. To quote from the [2014-2015 playing conditions](http://icc-live.s3.amazonaws.com/cms/media/about_docs/542bbed14ad2e-2%20_Standard_ODI_2014-15_Final_Oct_14.pdf), Law 41.2.3(a):

> During the first block of Powerplay Overs [...], only two fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area at the instant of delivery
>
> During the second block of Powerplay Overs only three fieldsmen shall be permitted outside this fielding restriction area at the instant of delivery

Note that this also answers your second question: the restriction is enforced an the instant of delivery, so fielders "walking in with the bowler" is absolutely fine so long as they are on or inside the 30 yard markers when the ball is delivered.

Comment: That is still ambiguous about *on the line*. As they say, in Cricket, the line always belongs to the umpire.

Comment: 1) No, it's not. "On the line" is not "outside the line" (it's not "inside the line" either), but the rule specifically refers to fielders *outside* the area. 2) "The line always belongs to the umpire" refers to one specific rule around the popping crease and doesn't apply in general.